# Write ElasticSearch response to CSV with Jackson CSV Mapper

Tags: java, csv, elasticsearch

I have a response from ElasticSearch which contains many nested objects. Trying to use Jackson to write this out as a CSV.

My response from ElasticSearch is inside a record:

```java
public record SearchRecord(String id, @JsonUnwrapped Map<String, Object> values) {}
```

where the actual results live inside the `values` property, and from what I've read on the Jackson readme should work as a `Map<String, Object>`

where I'm getting a bit lost is how I should be configuring the CSV mapper based on the above `record`

What I've attempted is

```java
@SneakyThrows
public void writeResults(final List<SearchRecord> searchRecords) {
    final CsvMapper csvMapper = CsvMapper.builder().build();

    csvMapper.writerWithSchemaFor(SearchRecord.class)
        .with(CsvSchema.emptySchema())
        .writeValue(new File("./output.csv"), searchRecords);
}
```

But that failed with

```java
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Incompatible types: declared root type ([simple type, class com.example.SearchRecord]) vs `java.util.LinkedList`
```

I found an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/189) with someone trying to do the same thing, which pointed me to using `@JsonUnwrapped` but that didn't help unfortunately.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

To write CSV with Jackson, I created a utility class:

```
public class CsvUtils<T> {

    private final Class<T> typeParameterClass;
    
    public CsvUtils(final Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

    // path of the folder where the CSV file will be saved
    private static final String SRC_TEST_RESOURCES_PATH = "./src/test/resources/";
    private static final String CSV_EXTENSION = ".csv";
    private static final String UNDERSCORE = "_";

    public void writeCSV(final String fileName, final List<T> records) throws IOException {
        final String fileNameWithTime = fileName + UNDERSCORE + System.currentTimeMillis() + CSV_EXTENSION;
        final File file = new File(SRC_TEST_RESOURCES_PATH + fileNameWithTime);

        final CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        mapper.configure(Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true);
        
        CsvSchema schema = getCsvSchema(mapper);

        final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(typeParameterClass).with(schema);
        
        writer.writeValues(file).writeAll(records);
    }
}
```

to use it

```
CsvUtils<SearchRecord> csvSearchRecord = new CsvUtils<>(SearchRecord.class);
csvSearchRecord.writeCSV("output", searchRecords);
```

Hope it works also for you.